# How to remove / delete an item from a Dojo Drag and Drop Source?

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop, dojo-dnd

I have the below Dojo DnD and I can't figure out how to delete and add item(s) from/to the `catalog` source.  What I ultimately want to do is allow the users to is:

1. Drag items from the `catalog` to the `wishlist`... this is working fine.
2. Delete any remaining items in the `catalog` that were not moved to the `wishlist` by clicking the **Clear List** button... need help here.
3. Be able to add new items to the `catalog` by clicking another button that is not listed in the below code... need help here.

To summarize, I need to know how to delete items and add items from/to the `catalog`, and have any moved items remain in the `wishlist`.

```js
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    require([ "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/dnd/Source", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(domClass, Source){
        var catalog = new Source("catalogNode");
        catalog.insertNodes(false, [
            { data: "Bushmaster <div id='5' style='display:none;'>5</div>"},
            { data: "Colt <div id='4' style='display:none;'>4</div>"},
            { data: "DPMS <div id='6' style='display:none;'>6</div>"},
            { data: "Glock <div id='2' style='display:none;'>2</div>"},
            { data: "Kahr Arms <div id='7' style='display:none;'>7</div>"},
            { data: "Marlin <div id='3' style='display:none;'>3</div>"},
            { data: "Remington <div id='78' style='display:none;'>78</div>"},
            { data: "Rock River Arms <div id='1' style='display:none;'>1</div>"},
            { data: "Smith & Wesson <div id='105' style='display:none;'>105</div>"}
        ]);
        catalog.forInItems(function(item, id, map){
            domClass.add(id, item.type[0]);
        });

        var wishlist = new Source("wishlistNode");

        new dijit.form.Button({
            label: "Clear List",
            onClick: function() {
                alert("Clearing Items");
            }
        },
        "clearListBtn");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all (remaining) elements in a source:

```
// e.g., var catalog = new Source("catalogNode");
catalog.selectAll().deleteSelectedNodes();
```

New items can be added at any time by using the very same `insertNodes()`:

```
catalog.insertNodes(false, additionalData);
```